# JS Bcrypt to c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to convert https://github.com/tutao/tutanota/blob/master/src/api/worker/crypto/Bcrypt.js to c#.

If I'm correct, the input of generateKeyFromPassphrase is as follow:

- passphrase = SHA256 string
- salt = Rand 16 byte string

Finally a string is returned with:

- Bcrypt with passphrase+salt with 8 iterations

I have build the following functions in c#

```
public static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
{
  // Create a SHA256   
  using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
  {
    // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
    byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

    // Convert byte array to a string   
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
      builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
  }
}

public static string CreateHash(string passphrase, string saltInput)
{
  // Generate a salt
  RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] salt = StringToByteArray(saltInput);
  provider.GetBytes(salt);

  // Generate the hash
  Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, 8);
  byte[] bytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(256);

  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
  byte[] array = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
  return array;
}
```

But my encoding isn't working, but I don't fully understand why (I'm new to c#).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using [an existing implementation](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net)? Also have you considered [argon2](https://github.com/alipha/csharp-argon2) instead?

Comment: I tried BCrypt.Net, but I couldn't get that to work. Also; I think the encryption self isn't that special, I just don't know the right way in c# :-)